# incomplete type not allowed, function dec/def and no classes

Tags: c++, c++14, forward-declaration, function-declaration

So i keep getting an "incomplete type not allowed error" on the emphasized call of function "out" on this and ive switched the function decs around, and i decided to not move on until i have this figured out because i can't find any non-class examples that aren't completely analogically opaque. Noob question but any help would be appreciated.

its supposed to be a simple fibonacci function but obviously i haven't written all the code.
Cpp 14 ( on g++, im getting syntax highlights suggesting its 11, however).

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 

int fib(int x);
int input();
void out(int p);

int fib(int x) {
    // int* prim;
    // int* sec;
    // *prim = 1;
    // *sec = 1;
    // int count = 

}

int main(){

    void out( fib( input() ) );  // error here // out on this line
    return 0;
}

int input (){
    int inp = 0;
    
}

void out(int p){
    std::cout << "the number is: " << p ;
}
```

Comment: Don't use bold in code blocks, it doesn't work. Use comments instead. That's not how you call a function. Drop the return type.

Comment: Voting to closeas a typo.  Remove the return type from your function call: `void out( fib( input() ) );` -> `out( fib( input() ) );`

Comment: ah good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
 int main(){
      void out( fib( input() ) );  // error here
 }
```

is interpreted to something like an instantiation of a variable of type `void` calling the constructor that accepts a `int` as first parameter,
instead you probably want this:

```
   int main(){
       out( fib( input() ) );  
   }
```

that is just a function call

Answer (score 0):

You don't need return type name to call function. Remove `void` on the error line.